# Wordpress error - Embeded code disappears while implementing Marquee

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a blog with multiple authors my contributing authors are unable to embed videos into their posts. When they click `"Publish"` or `"Save Draft"`, the `embed code DISAPPEARS`. It is completely stripped from the post.

This happens while using `Marquee` and also sometimes using video code from any source (YouTube, Metacafe, Dailymotion, Break.com -- you name it.)

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin that allows for additional tags. I'm not sure if anyone has already referenced this or not but thought I would share: Unfiltered MU (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/unfiltered-mu/).

Hope this works out with you..I also had similar problems